# Is there a predefined method to reset all elements in a (X)HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, xhtml

Like one can do with a form:

```
document.forms[0].reset();
```

But im not using a form as am using AJAX.. Will I have to cycle through all elements using JavaScript?

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript libraries/frameworks?

Comment: Im thinking about Closure but was hoping to put it off till i need the cross browser comaptibility, i.e. when I deploy it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and **dirty** trick would be to wrap the fields of the document in a form tag but make the onsubmit event return false, like so...

```
<form id="form_resetter" onsubmit="return false;">
...
</form>
```

This way the form will not submit but you can run...

```
document.getElementById('form_resetter').reset()
```

...on it resetting all field within.

But really you should put your AJAX enabled fields in a form tag anyway as that would be graceful degradation.

Comment: How is it graceful degradation? Putting <input> elements directly in the body seems to validate fine..

Comment: If you put a form tag around AJAX enabled fields it will allow that user to still submit the fields (form) and get a result back from your application if you program a form handler for that submission. Yahoo recently found that %2 of of traffic has JS turned off completely and other people on older browsers without access to an XmlHttpRequest object will not be able to use that part of your app -- unless you degrade gracefully. This is just best practice; there is no actual NEED to put it in.

Answer (score 1):

You should ***always*** use an HTML `<form>` element - even (and especially) if you're using AJAX.  It will be more usable, accessible, and will make your life as a developer easier.  Do a Google search for "ajax graceful degradation" or "accessible ajax" if you don't believe me; it's actually pretty easy.

For example, here's an AJAX form that degrades gracefully using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), the greatest JavaScript library on earth:

```
<form method="post" action="ajax/test.html" name="ajax-form" id="ajax-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form name</legend>
    <p><label for="username">Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" /></label></p>
    <p><label for="password">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" /></label></p>
    <p>
      <label for="option-a">Option A: <input type="radio" name="options" id="option-a" value="a" /></label><br/>
      <label for="option-b">Option B: <input type="radio" name="options" id="option-b" value="b" /></label><br/>
      <label for="option-c">Option C: <input type="radio" name="options" id="option-c" value="c" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="select-box">Select Box:
        <select name="select-box" id="select-box" size="1">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p class="buttons"><button type="submit">Submit</button> <button type="reset">Reset</button></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    var $ajaxForm = $('#ajax-form');

    // Create container to store ajax result
    $ajaxForm.find('.buttons').after($('<p class="result"/>'));

    // Bind event handler
    $ajaxForm.bind('submit', function(event, data) {
        // Simple ajax POST request
        // See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
        $.post($ajaxForm.attr('action'), 'ajax=1&' + $ajaxForm.serialize(), function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
        });

        // Disable default form submit behavior
        return false;
    });

    // Bind click handler to override "reset" behavior...
    // Although this really isn't necessary if you're using the HTML <form> element, which you should be...
    $ajaxForm.find('button:reset').bind('click', function(event, data) {
        var $els = $ajaxForm.find('input, textarea, select');
        $els.filter('input:text, input:password, textarea').val('');
        $els.filter('input:radio, input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        $els.filter('select').attr('selectedIndex', '');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
fieldset {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
fieldset legend {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: In jQuery you can now use $(function() { ... instead of $().ready(function() { ... or $(document).ready(function() { ...

Answer (score 0):

No, but it turns out its v. easy with a function once you have given your input elements a className:

```
function clearInput() {
  var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("inputFields");
  for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    switch(fields[i].tagName)
    {
      case "INPUT": fields[i].value = null; break;
      case "SELECT": fields[i].selectedIndex = 0; break; // ASSUMPTION: 0 is the default 
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you could also use:

```
getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
```

But then you have to check type === "text" otherwise your buttons and other input elements will have their value cleared too.

Comment: Isn't there a difference between a form reset and setting all fields to null? I thought a reset puts fields back to what their original value and selected index was when the page loaded.

Comment: True - in may case their original values were null and the selected index was 0.

Comment: getElementsByClassName() is not supported in IE <= 8 btw, see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods

Answer (score 0):

Add a form. [Make it work without JavaScript](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build). Progressively enhance it so that JavaScript overrides the normal functionality.

More users will be able to use the page, and you won't have to try to hack associated functionality back in.